# Investigating ping latency

Tags: lan, latency

Usually in a LAN I get smth like :

```
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

with the occasional 10ms. But today on a friend's home I found 32ms consistently when pinging the router.

The structure is very simple:
router - non manageable switch - patch panel - 20m cat5e in walls - wall socket - patch cord - lap top

*First question* : What are the possible causes for latency over 2-3ms on a simple network ?

- Damaged cables/patch cords
- Bad socket/patch panel connections
- Interference from electrical cables - shouldn't it rather cause dropped packets
- Busy network - this could be excluded though because usually intermittent
- Router firmware bug
- Computer Firewall
- Mismatching NIC configuration
- IP conflicts

*Second question* : What should I look for in this specific case ?

The same lap top pings at 1ms on my network, and speed & duplex is set to auto negotiation on NIC. I will connect directly to the router to check it and there is nothing else on the network to overload it. I will check other lines/wall sockets, but is this something that can be related to the physical wires ?

Comment: First question: Most of the stuff listed.

Comment: Second question. Connect laptop to router. Test. Connect at next furthest point. Test. Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

In order to discover where is the issue you can try to connect your laptop and do the ping test from the following positions (marked with an "X")

router - X - non manageable switch - X - patch panel - 20m cat5e in walls - wall socket - X - patch cord - lap top

Then compare the latencies at those points and you cna have an approximation about where the problem is.

Comment: I am also interested on the theory of this. So, can physical wire connections cause latency ? And what about electrical interference.

Comment: Never heard about physical connectors by themselves causing latency. Of course the wire can, as longer it is more latency. I have more suspects from the point of view of the intermediate devices.